# Using external viewer in Visual Studio Code latex-workshop

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, latex

I'm trying to use vscode's latex-workshop command `View in external viewer` to open my pdf in Okular. My `settings.json` file looks like this.

```
"latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.command": "okular",//
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "external", //
    "latex-workshop.view.pdf.external.viewer.args": [
        "--unique",
        "%PDF%"
    ]
```

When I attempt to use an external viewer, nothing happens, and the log file looks like:

```
[12:35:14.967][Viewer] Open external viewer for /path/to/filename.pdf
[12:35:14.967][Viewer] Execute the external PDF viewer command The command is okular:["--unique","/path/to/filename.pdf"].
[12:35:15.075][Viewer] The external PDF viewer stdout: 
[12:35:15.076][Viewer] The external PDF viewer stderr: okular: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

But, if I open a terminal and type `okular --unique /path/to/filename.pdf` then all works fine.